# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working in recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
public void serverCall(String Id, final String title, final String descrpiton) {
    ReUseComponets serverCall = new ReUseComponets(new ShopProductlisteners() {
        @Override
        public void showShopProductListnerResult(List<ShopProductModel> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                if(adapter==null) {
                    List<ShopProductModel> shopProductModelList = result;
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
                    adapter = new ShopSubCateogryAdapter(getActivity(), shopProductModelList, title, descrpiton);
                    emptytextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                emptytextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void showError(Throwable error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    serverCall.asyncPostShopProduct(Id, "en_IN");
}
```

This is my server Call code

```
@Override
public void onReceived(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String title = this.getArguments().getString(Constants.TITLE);
    String id = this.getArguments().getString(Constants.ID);
    String descrption = this.getArguments().getString(Constants.DESCRIPTION);
    serverCall(id, title, descrption);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Using this code I am trying to call server call. When I come back from next activity to previous fragment, then my Data list is not updating in adapter. Can any one please suggest me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in  serverCall() in else part

Comment: else part if data is not there then it should empty recyclerview

Comment: See my given  answer

Comment: read my comment @JRamesh

Comment: Try server call method calling in onResume method.

Comment: You shoud try to remove second parameter in adapter class.

Answer (score 2):

afaik, `notifyDataSetChanged()` only work inside the Adapter class. So, you can solve it by adding a method to change all the item list in the Adapter. Something like this (here we using `swap()` method):

```
public class ShopSubCateogryAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopSubCateogryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  ...

  private List<ShopProductModel> shopProductModelList;

  public void swap(List<ShopProductModel> shopProductModelList) {
    // use this. to refer your variable with class scope 
    // if your parameter has the same name with the variable class scope.
    this.shopProductModelList.clear();
    this.shopProductModelList.addAll(shopProductModelList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
  ..
}
```

Then you can use it with:

```
adapter.swap(result);
```

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/JgnSBXt5d5cDpXB7S7qwDW, https://paste.ofcode.org/tYVjHUEbYeJUFBa8AfF3C  i am trying with this but still its not wotking please help @ישו אוהב אותך

Comment: there is a little error in your code. You need to use `this.shopProductModelList` to refer your class variable.

Comment: I'll update my answer to show you what the change is needed.

Comment: what you have Updated i dint see any change

Comment: @ManojKumar: probably you need to refresh the browser. Check my answer revision at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47048114/revisions

Comment: look dear i tried ur revison also but i am getting duplicate record all

Comment: Is that means that the notifyDataSetChanged() working now? The duplication exists somewhere else. You need to clean up your code. Don't always create a new Adapter with `adapter = new ShopSubCateogryAdapter(getActivity(), shopProductModelList, title, descrpiton);` each time you get the response. You only need to update it by calling the `swap()` method. Move RecyclerView and adapter initialization to a method called `initRecyclerView()`

Comment: Another suggestion, you should move all the server data request and handle outside the RecyclerView adapter. The adapter should only do its job, i.e showing the data. Delegate processing the data to its activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If your adapter isn't null, you're not doing anything. You need to update your list and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

**Update** your **method** like this:

```
public void serverCall(String Id, final String title, final String descrpiton) {
    ReUseComponets serverCall = new ReUseComponets(new ShopProductlisteners() {
        @Override
        public void showShopProductListnerResult(List<ShopProductModel> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                if(adapter==null) {
                   //shopProductModelList initialize it globally
                    List<ShopProductModel> shopProductModelList = result;
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
                    adapter = new ShopSubCateogryAdapter(getActivity(), shopProductModelList, title, descrpiton);
                    emptytextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
               else{
                    // do what you want to add to your list like this:
                   // if you intialize shopProductModelList it globally then you can call it here
                    shopProductModelList.clear();
                    shopProductModelList = result;


                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
            } else {
                emptytextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

and remove this line from your **onReceived()** method

```
@Override
public void onReceived(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String title = this.getArguments().getString(Constants.TITLE);
    String id = this.getArguments().getString(Constants.ID);
    String descrption = this.getArguments().getString(Constants.DESCRIPTION);
    serverCall(id, title, descrption);
    // no need this line here.
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Did you add something in your adapter ?

Comment: NO i havent add any thing

Comment: First, something adds to your adapter's list then call this line.`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: adapter.clear();  will never work dude coz its not List its adapter

Comment: Then declare your list globally wait I update my ans.